# Series dot product with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a series with multiple *sets* of arrays.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = ['a', 'b', 'c']
w = pd.Series(data=[10, 5, 20, 6, 8, 5], 
              index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['foo', 'bar'], idx]))
w
Out[5]: 
foo  a    10
     b     5
     c    20
bar  a     6
     b     8
     c     5
```

so that `foo` is one array and `bar` is another. I want to multiply `foo` and `bar` with a correlation matrix. Basically I want to calculate `(w * m * w)**.5`

```
m = pd.DataFrame({idx[0]: [1.0, 0.5, 0.2],
                  idx[1]: [0.5, 1.0, 0.3],
                  idx[2]: [0.2, 0.3, 1.0]},
                 index=idx)
```

I tried both

```
 w.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: m.dot(x).dot(x)**.5)
```

and

```
 m.dot(w).dot(w)**.5
```

Both resulted in

```
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

The expected result should be this

```
foo  26.739483914241877
bar  14.45683229480096
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that `w` has a multi-index. Doing the same operation on a single array gives the expected result.

```
v = pd.Series(data=[10, 5, 20], index=idx)

m.dot(v).dot(v)**.5
Out[9]: 26.739483914241877
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

---

### EDIT

Using a workaround, dropping the outmost level of the multiindex inside a function, I got it to work. I am still open to other, perhaps cleaner solutions.

```
def calc(v, m):
    # Copy v and make a new index, dropping outmost index.
    u = v.copy()
    u.index = v.index.droplevel(0)
    return m.dot(u).dot(u)**.5

w.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: calc(x,m))
Out[13]: 
bar    14.456832
foo    26.739484
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Did you try to use numpy library to make matrix operations easily? https://hackr.io/blog/numpy-matrix-multiplication

Comment: I am aware of numpy. For various reasons I prefer having the index ('a', 'b', 'c'), thats why I want to stick with pandas. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: If you share the mathematical notation of the matrix dot operation and expected result instead of the pandas any help may be easier. Because matrixes has not aligned.

Comment: I want to friendly remind that you can simulate your calculation from this calculator: https://matrixcalc.org/tr/ If you don't get any error we can easily understand that there is no arithmetical error then we can focus on the code.

Comment: Please your calculation by copying the link of the page like that: http://matrixcalc.org/#%7B%7B2,2,2%7D,%7B2,2,2%7D,%7B2,2,2%7D%7D%2A%7B%7B9,9,9%7D,%7B9,9,9%7D,%7B9,9,9%7D%7D

Comment: The math is correct. Technically `dot` is the same as matrix multiplication. The problem is not the math but the programming. But I see there is a typo in my examples... it is supposed to be `(w' x m x w)^(1/2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way of doing it although it requires some manual operation when reshaping the array. If you find this answer useful, I can automate it for you.

```py
# First define a simple function to be used 

def calc_dot(array, m):
    return m.dot(array).dot(array)**.5

# Then, the rest becomes trivial 
names = w.index.droplevel(1).unique()

# Note you would need to set reshape of array manually 
pd.Series([calc_dot(x, m) for x in w.values.reshape(2,3)], index = names)
```

Comment: Yes. This works. The only problem I have with this is that the index is not necessarily sorted. By keeping the index on `x` (in your list comprehension) the `dot`-function automatically aligns `x` and `m`. Since your `x` is only the values, it is not necessarily aligned with `m` on the index. This was not stated in the original question I'll admit.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Foo and bar were how you indexed them and that is why the first one is foo and the other bar. Do you need this sorted? Your expected output says otherwise.

Comment: In principle yes. The true index (it's a constructed example) is not a, b and c and the order of the columns isnt alphabetical. But yes. Sorting would fix it.

Comment: Ok. Do you know how to sort it? Doesn't seem too difficult to me :)

Comment: Yes. I was hoping to exploit the thing i mentioned about dot aligning with the index and so forth... but it is just nitpicking. Your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

As a cleaner way to convert multi-index series to the matrix using `reshape` function may help:

```
q = w.values.reshape(3,2)
q
```

The output becames

```
array([[10,  5],
       [20,  6],
       [ 8,  5]], dtype=int64)
```

However, unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce the solution.